# purescript halogen: Append IProp to HTML

Tags: purescript, halogen

Is there a way to append `IProp`'s to `HTML`?

Here's an example of what i'm trying to do:

```
foo :: forall p i. H.HTML p i -> H.HTML p i
foo myElement = 
  addProp (HP.id_ "SomeId") myElement
```

Where `addProp` takes `myElement`, gives it the `Id` (or any other arbitrary property) and returns back this new element that is basically the same but has that new property added to it?

Or in other words, does this function `addProp` exist in some fashion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't exist no, as if it were to do so, it'd bypass the typechecking of valid properties that can be set on a given element, plus it'd let you say nonsensical things like `addProp` on a `HH.text` value.

It's not impossible to write though, as the property checking stuff isn't an intrinsic part of the `HTML` representation - it's a layer on top that refines it. `HTML` is just made up of normal data types, so you can pattern match on `HTML` values to manipulate as needs be.